# InvokeMember("Click") Web Browser control error C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, invokemember

I am getting this error when running my code.

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
>   ''System.MarshalByRefObject.InvokeMember(string,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object[],
>   System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[],
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo, string[])' is inaccessible due to
>   its protection level'

I see that when clicking the button it is finding the correct button name but it is not clicking it. Below is my full code.

```
//LOGIN 
    private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic d = wb.Document;
        var el = d.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        var button = d.GetElementsByTagName("button");

        d.GetElementsByname("login")[0].value = this.NameBox.Text;
        d.GetElementsByName("password")[0].value = this.PWBox.Text;
        d.GetElementsByname("save")[0].InvokeMember("login");enter code here

    }
```

This is the button code

```
<buttons>
        <button name="save" class="k-btn-dark" type="submit">Login</button>
```

The Password and Username fields generate correctly but I get the "inaccessible" error on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a problem of class accessibility ? or function ?

Look at this post which talks about Resources but it could be the same for your case: ['Resource' is inaccessible due to its protection level](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/6faf7ac7-1ca1-45fd-944c-a2250d19f3f5/resource-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level?forum=silverlightnet)

Comment: I think you are correct because if I change InvokeMember ("submit") to ("Click") I am getting the same error. So it is not finding the button it is hitting the exception before firing. How would I fix this though? I cant seem to find the "Access Modifier" option that post was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT!

```
d.GetElementsByName("save")[0].Click();
```

No need for the InvokeMember.